# Using XMPP how to get notification on chatroom creation to all participants

Tags: xmpp, ejabberd, openfire, strophe.js

I am using Openfire as an XMPP server and strophe as an XMPP client. If a chatroom `c1` is created by a user `a` and participants are `b,c,d`. But `b and c` are online and they have an active connection with `XMPP server(Openfire)` So, how `b and c` users can join the room by getting the notification on creating of the chatroom. Is there any option available as a feature of XMPP or in Openfire?

Comment: If the participants are online, they do receive message with invite from Room, you mean you are not receiving any message from server to online participants when room is created?

Comment: @ShoaibAhmadGondal yeah I am using strophejs, whether any configuration need to be done from openfire side?

Comment: I haven't used Strophe. When you create a new chatroom, is it created successfully? Can you see it from Openfire Admin console?

Comment: @ShoaibAhmadGondal yeah if i am creating using admin console, I am able to see it

Comment: @ShoaibAhmadGondal but invite room should be sent from the other client right XEP-0045, it is not automcatically sent by server?